# Where do I see IIS 7.5 after installion?

Tags: windows-xp, iis-7.5

I had IIS 5.1 and just installed IIS 7.5

But when I go to adminstrative tools > internet information services, I see my computer name and under version it says IIS 5.1. I tried disconnect and connect but no luck.

Anyone knows how to use my new IIS?

Comment: What OS did you install it on?

Comment: On Windows XP .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed IIS 7.5 Express, the full IIS 7.5 only runs on Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008R2.

IIS Express does not have a user interface nor any entries in your start menu. You usually use it from within Visual Studio or Web Matrix.

There are some third party tools that add a UI to it, [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com) has some.

The files are in:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express
```

and the configuration for your sites is stored in:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

On XP this path looks a bit different